# How to loop through all sheets to get cell values to create a dropdown box?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets Spreadsheet with multiple sheets that contain the same Column Headers. I am trying to pull data from range "A2:A" from all of the sheets and create a dropdown box with all of the cell values, but at the moment it's only giving me a dropdown box with cell values from the last sheet.

```
function getCategoryList() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var lastrow = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()
  
  
   var dynamicList = spreadsheet.getRange('A2:A' + lastrow); 
   var arrayValues = dynamicList.getValues();

   var rangeRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(arrayValues);

   console.log(arrayValues)

   spreadsheet.getRange('Main!C4').setDataValidation(rangeRule);

  
}


function doForAllTabs() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
     var lastrow = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()
  var allSheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
 
  
  allSheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
    if(sheet.getSheetName() !== "Main") {
      sheet.activate();
      
      getCategoryList()
      
    }    
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current code datavalidation is written to the cell Main!C4 after a single sheet is processed inside the sheets-loop. In other words, the datavalidation is overwritten time and again. What is needed is the consolidation of values in an array that then is written to Main!C4. See if this helps.

```
function setDataValidation() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var values = allColsA(ss, 'Main', 'A2:A');
ss.getRange('Main!C4').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
.requireValueInList(values));
}
```

EDITED to include an array with excluded sheets...

```
function allColsA(spreadsheet, targetSheetName, range) {
var arr, excluded; 
arr = [[]];
excluded = [targetSheetName, 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'];
spreadsheet.getSheets().filter(sh => excluded.indexOf(sh.getName()) === -1)
    .forEach((s, i) => {
        arr = arr.concat(s.getRange(range)
                .getValues())
    })
return  arr.filter(String).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I forgot to mention that the first worksheet is different that the rest, I am having trouble reworking my script to skip the worksheet "Main" that's different from the rest during the loop.

Comment: @thetran209: I changed the second function. See if that works? If not, can you specify what you mean with 'different from the rest'. The code provided skips the sheet 'Main' in the loop. Is there another sheet that should be skipped?

Comment: At the moment while I'm learning Javascript and Google App Script, for now 'Main' is the only sheet I am skipping. I do plan to skip more sheets in the future by sheetname so I know I will have to create a variable to exclude those sheets somehow.

Comment: It works great now, but if there's nothing in the cell(s) I get the error: "TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value (line 9, file "allColsA")

Comment: @thetran209: If you wish to skip more sheets, you can included an array with the excluded sheets. See the updated code above. Secondly, the error shown when no values were found should be gone too.